# Как обновить данные в строке таблицы

Tags: php, sql, ооп, telegram

Есть кусок кода. Если пользователь уже заходил, то по id берем полностью строчку из таблицы, если зашел впервые, то берем данные из json и инсертим в базу. Вопрос такой, как в первом случае мне получить все актуальные данные из json (id не меняется), а не старые из select, думаю надо сделать update, а потом уже select. Но как это сделать в ооп стиле понять не могу.

```
private function startBot($chat_id, $data)
    {
        $user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bot_shop_profile WHERE user_id = :user_id");
        $user->execute(['user_id' => $chat_id]);
        if ($user->rowCount() == 0) {
            $newUser = $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO bot_shop_profile SET user_id = :user_id, first_name = :first_name, last_name = :last_name, phone = :phone, adress = :adress, action = 'start', username = :username");
            $newUser->execute([
                'user_id' => $chat_id,
                'first_name' => $data['message']['chat']['first_name'],
                'last_name' => $data['message']['chat']['last_name'],
                'username' => $data['message']['chat']['username'],
                'phone' => '',
                'adress' => '',
            ]);
        } else {
            @$this->setActionUser("start", $chat_id);
        }
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Безусловно выполняем INSERT IGNORE. Если такой пользователь отсутствует, запись вставится, иначе вставка будет проигнорирована (соответственно необходимо наличие уникального индекса, который позволит обнаружить факт наличия записи). После этого столь же безусловно делаем SELECT и используем полученные данные.

Comment: не понимаю чем это мне поможет? в листинге после if именно это и просходит. как мне для старых пользователей делать update и одновременно подгружать их данные для работы?

Comment: *не понимаю чем это мне поможет?* А Вы попробуйте подумать над происходящим.

Comment: Фрагмент ``else {@$this->setActionUser("start", $chat_id);  }`` заменить на ``$user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM bot_shop_profile WHERE user_id = :user_id");
        $user->execute(['user_id' => $chat_id]); @$this->setActionUser("start", $chat_id);``  Т.е. после проверки/добавления юзер уже есть, можно действовать без ветвлений.